# Метод save()

Tags: python, django

Есть заполненная форма, которая записывается через метод `save()`, как перед тем, как записать сделать небольшие изменения над полем, и тогда записывать в базу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К сожалению нет под рукой джанги, попробуйте так, но не гарантирую =)

```
form = MyForm(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    form.cleaned_data['myfield'] = 'some_value'
    form.save()
```

Answer (score 2):

вот так

```
form = Form(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    model = form.save(commit = False) #не пишет в базу, возвращает модель
    model.sex = "female" #то самое небольшое изменение, меняем атрибут sex на "female"
    model.save()         #записываем
```